# Proving Double Negation with conditional proof

Tags: logic

How can we show that, 
A ≡ ~~A 
Without simply using the rule of double negation, but by showing it as a conditional proof?

Comment: Can you point out which proof system you mean? There are logics in which this cannot be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a proof by exhaustion using only the definition of ~

> A ϵ {T, F}
>
> Let A = T
>
> ~~(A) = ~~(T) = ~(~T) = ~F = T = A
>
> Let A = F
>
> ~~(A) = ~~(F) = ~(~F) = ~T = F = A
>
> In both cases we find ~~A ≡ A, QED